# Replacement brake pads for SRAM Force 1/CX 1

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, cyclocross, sram, brake-pads

I'm looking to replace the default pads that come with the SRAM Force 1/CX 1. I can't tell if they're metallic or organic. I ended up purchasing the organic version https://www.competitivecyclist.com/sram-road-disc-brake-pads-organic, but they have a high pitch squeal. I cleaned the disc beforehand with isopropyl alcohol and bed in the pads on the first ride. If the original pads were metallic, would the rotors not be compatible with organic pads? The rotors still have ton of life in them, so just looking for a brake pad that works correctly, or any other fixes.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/changing-disc-brake-pad-material-while-keeping-same-rotors may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Should be OK, I have not heard of problems changing to different types. 
Organics are normally quieter and less prone to squeal than metallic pads, in fact its one of their main advantages.

I would go though the normal steps for dealing with squealing brakes. Align the calipers, clean and bed in. As the pads are new, and you cleaned the rotors, I would align and see it if goes. If that does not work, very lightly surface the rotors and discs with fine emery paper and redo bedding in.

In some cases its just the  combination of pads, disk, brakes and frame don't work. If you can't live with it, changing to a different pad will often fix it.